# Standalone installer for AI Chrome extension?

Tags: accessibility-insights

I'd like to use Accessibility Insights to check contrast on a website I'm working on, but the code is on a VM with no internet access. I looked at using the Accessibility Insights Windows application, since I could just copy that installer up to the VM, but when I use it to check a webpage on my own machine, it says "Chromium components should be scanned with a web-based scanner."

Where can I get a standalone installer for the Chrome extension for Accessibility Insights?

Answer (score 0):

While there is no standalone installer for the web extension, we offer the same scanning engine as a CLI tool at https://www.npmjs.com/package/accessibility-insights-scan. You would need to render the contained HTML to a local web page, then use the CLI to scan the rendered contents.

Accessibility Insights for Windows does not have access to the HTML or the DOM, so the "How to fix" suggestions on the browser element are not truly actionable without additional information. Running Accessibility Insights for Web (or the CLI equivalent) will provide far more actionable suggestions.

Failures of this rule may be ignored where it is infeasible to render the contained HTML separately into a browser.

Thanks for using Accessibility Insights!

--Dave Tryon
Accessibility Insights team

Comment: Thanks, this is great info! I also thought of trying to save various pages as standalone HTML files, copying them to my local machine, and running AI on them there.

In the end, the solution I found is that I can navigate in my local browser to the website hosted by the VM (http://vm-ip-address/whatever) and avoid the issue altogether, running the AI Chrome extension locally.